# Capturing errors in a transaction and rollback - declare not valid at this position

Tags: mysql

Trying to craft a transaction from the code to send to MySQL.

```
START TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (`firstname`,`lastname`)
 VALUES('john','Doe');

SET EMP_ID = last_insert_id();
 //do some inserts here that fail

COMMIT;
```

Now, when the other inserts into child tables fail I see that just the first insert being committed. TO avoid that I need to capture error and set rollback on error being triggered. When I include the declare statements for error it just fails saying

"Declare is not valid at this position. expecting EOF ;" Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

```
START TRANSACTION

DECLARE error BOOL DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;

....other code
```

Comment: "If some statment fails should not commit this", I need help figuring out how to implement this. Lets assume I made an insert to an employee detail table that violated null constraint. It still inserts john doe into the employee table. Was under the impression that this is when you declare an error and continue handler. But that declare statement gives a syntax error as well.

Comment: Declarations must prefer `START TRANSACTION` statement. If you need shown order you must enclose them into a block: `START TRANSACTION; BEGIN DECLARE ...; other code; END; COMMIT;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DECLAREs` must be placed before all executable code in a `BEGIN...END` block.  `START TRANSACTION is 'executable'.

So...

```
DELIMITER //    
CREATE ...
BEGIN
    DECLARE _rollback DEFAULT 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    ... -- other executables
    IF _rollback = 0
    THEN  COMMIT;
    ELSE  ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

You can also have nested `BEGIN..END` blocks.  But the declarations in your example should *probably* go at the beginning of the stored routine.  This is because `BEGIN..END` blocks provide "scoping" for variables such as `_rollback`.

Comment: Nesting does not produce scoping problems: `START TRANSACTION; BEGIN DECLARE _rollback DEFAULT 0; executables; IF _rollback = 0 THEN  COMMIT; ELSE  ROLLBACK; END IF; END;` - transaction start and finalize do not have to be in the same scope block.

Comment: Thanks. So does the create statement need to create a stored procedure? What if I do not want to create a stored proc.

Comment: @user275157 - Outside of a stored routine, you cannot use `DECLARE` and `IF..THEN..ELSE..END IF`.  Those things must be done in your client programming language.

Comment: So I send a separate query for begin transaction, end transaction setting the variables outside in my programming language. That sounds doable. I was under the assumption that there would be a way to send a script without creating a stored proc. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user275157 - What is your client language?

Comment: It is nodejs and I wanted to use the mysql library to directly send queries instead of using ORMs like sequelize that seem bloated